# SharePoint 2013 getting all webs in a given site collection including root web using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, client-object-model

Using JSOM I am trying to get the collection of all the webs(sub-sites) **including the root** **web** of a given site collection and display there title.

Below is the code snippet. But it throws error "get_allWebs()"property is not supported.

```
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web(); 
        var siteColl = context.get_site();
         var webSubSites = siteColl.get_allWebs();

          context.load(webSubSites, 'Include(Title, ServerRelativeUrl)');

         context.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {  

         for (var x = 0; x < webSubSites.get_count(); x++) {
             var subWeb = webSubSites.itemAt(x);                 
            alert(subWeb.get_title());
          }

        }),
         Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
             console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' +   args.get_stackTrace());
         }));
```

I am able to get all the subwebs\subsites, but not rootweb.

Comment: try this one: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/13/sharepoint-2010-object-model-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `Property is not supported` occurs since [SP.Web object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245288%28v=office.15%29.aspx) does not contain `AllWebs` property. From another hand [SP.Web object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245288%28v=office.15%29.aspx) exposes [SP.Web.webs property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246370%28v=office.15%29.aspx) returns *all Web sites immediately beneath the Web site, excluding children of those Web sites*.

You could use [SP.Web.parentWeb property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246539%28v=office.15%29.aspx) in order to return `parent web` that corresponds to `root web` for 1st level sub site, the following example demonstrates how it could be achieved:

```
function getWebs()
{
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web(); 
   var site = context.get_site();
   var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
   var subWebs = rootWeb.get_webs();

   context.load(subWebs, 'Include(Title, ServerRelativeUrl,ParentWeb)');
   context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {  
         for (var i = 0; i < subWebs.get_count(); i++) {
            var subWeb = subWebs.itemAt(i);
            var parentWeb = subWeb.get_parentWeb();  //parent web ==  root web
            console.log(subWeb.get_title());
          }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
   );   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script that would get you the root web's title. To get the sub-sub sites, you'd need a recursive function.

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
// context = new SP.ClientContext(siteRelativeUrl);
var web = context.get_web(); 
var siteColl = context.get_site();
var rootWeb = siteColl.get_rootWeb();
var subWebCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

context.load(rootWeb);
context.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){
     window.console && console.log(rootWeb.get_title());

  },
  function (sender, args) {
     alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
  }
);
```

Note: web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null); would only return the sites you have access to. Else some user may get access denied when trying to read web properties.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aveenav. Your post helped me fetch the subsites for a user with read-only permission

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you need to do something like this:

```
 var rootWeb = context.get_rootWeb();
```