# Get all subsites and rootweb of a site collection using JSOM

Tags: client-object-model

I have used the following code from [Most efficient way to get all sub sites under a site collection/sub site using JSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130403/most-efficient-way-to-get-all-sub-sites-under-a-site-collection-sub-site-using-j?rq=1)

```
    function getAllWebs(success,error)
    {
       var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
       var result = [];
       var level = 0;
       var getAllWebsInner = function(web,result,success,error) 
       {
          level++;
          var ctx = web.get_context();
          var webs = web.get_webs(); 
          ctx.load(webs,'Include(Title,Webs)');
          ctx.executeQueryAsync(
          function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
              var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
              result.push(web);
              if(web.get_webs().get_count() > 0) {
                getAllWebsInner(web,result,success,error);
              }   
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
       },
       error);
  }; 

  getAllWebsInner(web,result,success,error);    
}   

getAllWebs(
    function(allwebs){
       for(var i = 0; i < allwebs.length;i++){
         console.log(allwebs[i].get_title());   
       }
    },
    function(sendera,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

but this one is only returning all subsites' titles, except for the rootweb. I have tried a few ways but not successful. So what should I need to do to access to the rootweb as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could consider the following **modified** example for enumerating *all sites within site collection*:

```
function enumWebs(propertiesToRetrieve, success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var rootWeb = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
   var result = [];
   var level = 0;
   ctx.load(rootWeb,propertiesToRetrieve);
   result.push(rootWeb);
   var colPropertiesToRetrieve = String.format('Include({0})',propertiesToRetrieve.join(',')); 
   var enumWebsInner = function(web,result,success,error) 
   {
      level++;
      var ctx = web.get_context();
      var webs = web.get_webs(); 
      ctx.load(webs,colPropertiesToRetrieve);
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
                var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                result.push(web);
                enumWebsInner(web,result,success,error);
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
        },
        error);
   };
   enumWebsInner(rootWeb,result,success,error);    
}
```

[Gist: enumWebs.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/b1e5273139607363bef9)

Key Points:

- `propertiesToRetrieve parameter` is used for specifying what Web
  properties to retriece

**Usage**

Print web sites title:

```
enumWebs(['Title'],
   function(webs){
       for(var i = 0; i < webs.length;i++){
          console.log(webs[i].get_title());                               
       }
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should request for the root web

```
var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
ctx.load(web,'Include(Title)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(...);
```

[SharePoint 2013 getting all webs in a given site collection including root web using JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103553/sharepoint-2013-getting-all-webs-in-a-given-site-collection-including-root-web-u)